# Function that Contains a For Loop Checking for Sum of Odd Numbers in Vector in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that contains a for loop which checks for how many odd numbers are in a vector.

I've tried a few variations but it either prints the whole column or the number 1 the length of the column. Any suggestions?

```
# counter
odd_count <- 0

for(i in 1:length(MAJOR$Unemployed)) {
  if(i %% 2 != 0) {
    odd_count <- odd_count +  1
    print(odd_count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean how many odd numbers between 0 and the vector?

Comment: No, I have a column of data (MAJOR$Unemployed), and I am trying to find the sum of how many observations are an odd number

Comment: you should wrap it in a function and return odd count outside of the for loop. Your code looks good just a few adjustments

Comment: Like this? odd_numbers <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(MAJOR$Unemployed)) {
    if(i %% 2 != 0) {
      odd_count <- odd_count +  1
    }
  }
  print(odd_count)
}
odd_numbers(MAJOR$Unemployed)

Comment: I do get an actual answer when I make that change but I don't know if it is correct without manually counting

Comment: Skip the loop and use the vectorization of R with  `sum(MAJOR$Unemployed %% 2 !=0)`

Comment: @Dave2e - I do like that answer better but unfortunately required to use a ```for``` loop

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working!

```
odd_count <- 0
odd_numbers <- function(x){
  for(i in MAJOR$Unemployed) {
    if(i %% 2 != 0) {
      odd_count <- odd_count +  1
    }
  }
  print(odd_count)
}
odd_numbers(MAJOR$Unemployed)
```

I do agree this way is more efficient and way easier:

```
sum(MAJOR$Unemployed %% 2 !=0)
```

So thank you @Dave2e!

I was able to double-check my function against this succinct code.

Comment: replace `MAJOR$Unemployed` in the for loop with x. That way, any series of vectors you pass it to it, it will sum it up. right now, no matter what you pass to your function it will only loop over the Unemployed vector because your for loop is doing everything and your function doesn't pass anything.

Comment: Also, it is better to bring the odd_count ref variable inside the function but not in the for loop because it doesn't need to be global. Other than that looks good